# How to use the LinkedList class' AddAfter method

Tags: c#, linked-list

After looking on MSDN I've found that I am supposed to have a target node for the following code:

```
var listOffences = new LinkedList<string>();
listOffences.AddFirst("aaa");
listOffences.AddAfter("bbb"); // Requires target node
```

I have no idea how to get the required information for the first node, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you want it at the end you'd use 'AddLast', otherwise yes, you need to know which node it goes after.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`AddFirst`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132172(v=vs.110).aspx) will return the newly added node you can use that in `AddAfter`

```
var listOffences = new LinkedList<string>();
var firstNode = listOffences.AddFirst("aaa");
// you may not need the `secondNode` returned. 
var secondNode = listOffences.AddAfter(firstNode, "bbb"); // Requires target node
```

or if don't need the second node reference then:

```
listOffences.AddAfter(firstNode, "bbb");
```

Comment: Thanks, simpler than I imagined.

Answer (score 3):

To get the first node of a linked list, you can just used LinkedList.First.

```
var listOffences = new LinkedList<string>();
listOffences.AddFirst("aaa");
var firstNode = listOffences.First;
listOffences.AddAfer(firstNode, "bbb");
```

Alternatively, you can use the find methods to find specific values.

```
var listOffences = new LinkedList<string>();
listOffences.AddFirst("aaa");
listOffences.AddLast("bbb");
listOffences.AddLast("ccc");
listOffences.AddAfter(listOffences.Find("bbb"), "ddd");
```

A breakdown of this section:

1. Create the LinkedList
2. Add "aaa" first
3. Add "bbb" onto the end of the list
4. Add "ccc" onto the end of the list
5. Find the node containing "bbb" and add "ddd" to the list after the "bbb" node.

Comment: Another good answer, nice to know of the LinkedList.Find() method.

Comment: Something to take note of is that you should probably be pulling the result of Find() into another variable and doing a null check. If you try to add after null, your program will throw an exception.